# i got a "linker command failure"

Tags: xcode, debugging, swift, compilation

ld: file not found: /Users/eduardoRojas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoveThemNOW-gkrqwdnrkcwmgygipvtpedxmqpjz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Move Them NOW.app/Move Them NOW
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

i don't know what is happening please help

Comment: Use Xcode's Report Navigator to look at the whole build that failed.  There is probably another error that was reported **before** that one.  It's usually the result of a problem, not the cause.

Comment: i got it fixed using this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197542/error-after-renaming-xcode-6-project-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-u