# Cannot build when changing folder location in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors

I've got an Xcode project that runs perfectly. Then I change the folder location by moving it to a 'iOS projects' folder at the same location and now it couldn't compile anymore, even when I move it back to the original location. Here is what I got:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete your app from the phone or "reset contents and settings" from the simulator.
2. Clean your build cmd+option+shift+k
3. Clear out your derived data.
4. Build and hopefully there are no errors.

If you're getting errors after that go here and follow the instructions on the accepted answer.
[Error after renaming Xcode 6 project: "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197542/error-after-renaming-xcode-6-project-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-u)

Comment: I've just done these steps and the errors still remain.
I don't have the test project in targets, so I guess I can't follow those instructions :( I deleted the test target for some reason before.

Comment: @FlySoFast http://www.sirentuan.com/382538/codep1/xcode-llvm-50-error There is another link I found awhile back when this error happened to me that I'm trying to find again but let me know if this link helps so I can stop searching.

Comment: I followed that link and some other related ones but no luck so far. Seems like I have to copy all my code to a new project..

Comment: @FlySoFast I can't find the link for the life of me. But it is something to do with going into your project by right clicking it and "show package contents" then you delete something inside there, and then you show package contents in something else and delete something inside that too. Sorry I can't be of more help that than though. If I happen to struggle upon it I'll post it.

Comment: @FlySoFast Did you get this figured out or still having problems?

Comment: I havent figured it out yet. I even tried to reinstall Xcode.

Comment: @FlySoFast I know it's a pain but you might just want to copy your classes and xibs over to a new project and then link everything up again there as a last resort

Comment: Yeah that's my problem too. I had so many issues while developing project