# Linker error ios while renaming the project name in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors

I tried to rename my project in xcode and i get linker error .
Then i followed these steps : [Error after renaming Xcode 6 project: "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197542/error-after-renaming-xcode-6-project-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-u)

**But still i was not able to remove this error.
Then i renamed my project to its original one and now my run button in xcode is disabled .** 
**I got stuck ...!!!!**

Comment: whats error you get?post it here

Comment: Run button is disabled now ....

Comment: At first it was showing that some files are missing....that files has same name of my previous name of my project......i have already renamed all the files ........

Answer (score 0):

I have tried (for you) same and also i'm getting same error. And also renamed it as previous.

Restart Xcode and Press `Command + Shift + K` [clean project] or `Command + Shift + Alt + K` that will delete all of the products and intermediate files in the build folder.

After that try to rebuild.

**Suggestions**

To rename app name kindly go to Build Settings -> Product Name -> Change it to whatever you need.

[image]