# Cannot load underlying module for XCTest

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest

I'm working in swift on Xcode and by default it creates a test file that references XCTest.

When I set the target membership to my main project it causes this error

> Cannot load underlying module for XCTest

If this target membership is not set the tests runs properly and everything works fine.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

The main project does not link with the XCUnit framework. You should create a separate testing target for your project, if one does not already exist, and add your test source files to that target.

1. Select your project in the Project Navigator. This will open the project's settings in the editor.
2. Click the "+" button at the bottom of the column listing your Targets.

[image]

3. **If you are working on an iOS project template**, select `iOS > Test > iOS Unit Testing Bundle`.

   **If you are working on an OS X project template**, select `OS X > Test > OS X Unit Testing Bundle`.

Comment: Meanwhile for iOS it's called iOS UITesting Bundle (use it for UI Tests) or iOS Unit Testing Bundle (it's for Unit Tests...)

Answer (score 195):

Double check that the file in question is not in the main target but instead only the test target. Only the test target will have that framework to import.

Comment: If it helps.  Select your 'Non Test' Target -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources.   Make sure your "ClassTest.swift" isn't in the normal build target.

Comment: And if it is in the main bundle and the testing bundle how do you remove it from the main bundle.

Comment: Thanks @NickN, you pointed out the exact issue I was having and thats fixed now !

Comment: IF its on the Test Target then I can't seem to access any of my main testing methods in my main Target.

Comment: thanks it worked like a charm. just removing the test files worked.

Answer (score 33):

You've just added your tests file/class into main target and not into test target by mistake. Simple as that.

Solution:

1) Remove test file from "Compile Sources" list on "Build Phases" tab for main target

2) Add same file into "Compile Sources" on "Build Phases" tab for test target

It must resolve the issue

Answer (score 15):

I get this error if I create a macOS dynamic framework target, which links to `XCTest.framework` (the target is a framework target, not a testing target!).

In this case the problem is solved by adding

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks
```

to project's "Build Settings / Framework Search Paths".

Comment: Better: `$(PLATFORM_DIR)/Developer/Library/Frameworks` in case you have multiple versions of Xcode installed under different names (e.g. release and beta versions).

Comment: Thanks @robmayoff this was the correct solution ;-)

Comment: This is the correct answer when building a framework for testing support.

Answer (score 10):

After lots of troubleshooting and bouncing around Stack Overflow pages such as this one, I managed to find one detail that was not mentioned on the other iOS Unit Test troubleshooting pages.

If your project uses CocoaPods, make sure to include your test target nested inside your main application's target. Your podfile might not include it if you created your test target *after* running `pod init`. Your podfile should look something like this:

```
target 'YourApp' do
    target 'YourAppTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        # Pods for testing
    end
end
```

Remember to save your podfile and run `pod install` after doing so.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

This maybe a little late but what you have to do is:

Click on File > New > Target > iOS Unit Testing Bundle.

And then add your tests in there. This worked for me. The problem was that I didn't select create unit tests when I created my project. 
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

While the accepted answer solves this problem for majority of times, there is one more way you can come across this error.

**If you have already ensured that:**

*As pointed out by @pwc @nick-n and others*

1. The `ClassTest.swift` file for target membership by ensuring that it is **only** attached to the Testing target.
2. The `ClassTest.swift` is **not** visible under you main app target > Build Sources > Compile Sources

**Here is what else you can check:**

in your `.podspecs` file

Ensure that your `source_files` does not directly or indirectly includes the testing directory.

**for example :**

```
s.source_files = ["Classes/**/*.{swift}", "Classes/**/*.{xib}"]
s.exclude_files = ["Classes/Exclude", "Classes/MyPodProjTests/"]
```

Note that `Classes/**/*.{swift}` includes everything overriding the fact that the directory `MyPodProjTests` must be excluded.

**Solution:**

```
s.source_files = ["Classes/MyPodProj/**/*.{swift}", "Classes/**/*.{xib}"]
```

*Note:
This is extremely edge case and completely human error but I thought it will be worth pointing out.*

Comment: Excellent remark, I had included everything in my `s.source_files`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This problem occur two times in your project.

1. When you Don't Add UnitTestingBundle in your project when create a New Project.
2. When you install CocoaPods in Your Project sometime not every time.

**1:Answer:**

- Go to the File Click on File.
- Then You see First option New Click on it.
- After Clicking on it you see Some Option Click on Target.
- And then in the Searchbar Search IOS Unit Testing Bundle and Add Problem is solved.
- if Compiler can't give you a permission to add this then try Second Method when is given Below.

**2. Answer CocoaPod Problem:**

- Go to the Product Click on the Product.
- Click on clean or press cmd+k.
- Problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Target Membership is checked off for all the modules when the test framework is selected. You can view the Target Membership option by selecting View->Utilities->Show File Inspector

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was making the tests for a private pod, so in the podspec was like:

```
s.test_spec 'Tests' do |test_spec|
test_spec.source_files = 'Tests/*.swift' end
```

But in the Podfile I forgot to bring the test specification, as such:

```
target 'MyApp' do
use_frameworks!
pod 'CoconutLib', '~> 1.0', :testspecs => ['Tests'] end
```

Answer (score 0):

I did all the above, but still I was not allowed to access the methods I wanted to test. But before I wrote any test case built the project once and then the methods were accessible to test. So do try it and let me know if it solved any ones problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution for me was to:

1. Select my scheme
2. Edit Scheme...
3. Then when Scheme configuration window is opened select left tab named "Test" to be redirected here: 
   [image]
4. Like you can see my UITests are not added here but exist in my project so I had just to tap plus button and select my UITests target like this:
   [image]
5. Then tap "Add" button and close configuration view
6. Finish with a clean of project and try again it should work
7. And don't forget to verify that too: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1954/_index.html

Hope this answer will help.

PS: one last think in my Test target in build settings I had to check these property that was not configured correctly:

```
DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT = dwarf; 
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = YES;
VALIDATE_PRODUCT = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as @Alfishe mentioned above:

You have to remove the test files from `Compiler Sources` under `Build Phases`

As shown below

---

[image]

Comment: If you do that you can't execute the tests, as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

Check Target Membership of your Test class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Unit Testing Bundle` as a target should be created beforehand

[[How to add it]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55937942/4770877)