# use the XCGLogger error XCTest no loading

Tags: xcglogger

XCGLogger works in both iOS and OS X projects. It is a Swift library intended for use in Swift projects.

I get the following error:

> Cannot load underlying module for "XCTest"

What can be the cause of this error and how can I fix this?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking, in fact, I don't even see a question. But perhaps this link will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965397/cannot-load-underlying-module-for-xctest

Comment: did that link help resolve your issue?