# Cannot load underlying module for XCTest after add language

Tags: swift, xcode

My app work well, in the last days I update a language and everything it's ok, today i put the 3th with the same process and my app give me this error "Cannot load underlying module for XCTest" I have just try a lot of solutions but without win...

Answer (score -1):

This is a shot in the dark, as it's not entirely clear what the question here is. If I'm understanding right, though, you added another localization (the 3rd language supported by your app), and this now led to you seeing the `Cannot load underlying module for XCTest` error. If that's the case, I'd check that your new localization file is set to the right target: it should be set to the main target, not your testing target.

[This question and it's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965397/cannot-load-underlying-module-for-xctest) also seem relevant here, if it's not your localization file it sounds like a file has the wrong target membership.