# Adding Unit and UI tests to an existing project in Xcode

Tags: xcode

Lets say I have an existing project in Xcode, and for whatever reason, did not add Unit Tests or UI Tests. Can I add the test projects to the project later in Xcode 7?

Comment: isn't this the answer to your question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/32009790/1869369

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Yes!

You can add new test targets for UI and unit tests by navigating `File > New > Target > Test`. When that's done, add new test cases by navigating `File > New > File > Source`.

[image: Test Target]

Comment: If you are using C files with your Swift Unit Tests you may also need to point your new Target to the Bridging Header file & ensure any Header files locations are known.  You access both settings via the /Build Settings against the Target.

Answer (score 20):

Tests are targets.

Select the project in the navigation view then `Menu File` > `New` > `Target…` and  `Test` of the proper SDK.

Choose `UI Testing Bundle` or `Unit Test Bundle`.

Repeat the procedure to add the other test bundle.

Answer (score 15):

**Xcode add a test to a target**

One more variant `Xcode 10.2.1` using `Test Navigator`

1. <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd> or `View -> Navigators -> Show Test Navigator`
2. `Right click` or `+` at the bottom
3. `New Unit Test Target...` or `New UI Test Target...`

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Follow this steps,it works's fine

1.Select the project.

2.Targets->Click the + button->Add iOS UITesting Bundle or iOS UnitTesting Bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do that in **Xcode 15.0**

[image: Click +]

A template view will appear search test:
[image: Template View]

[image: Confirm view]

[image: Added]

[image: Here is test case file]