# Xcode Base.lproj and Main storyboard in restoring files

Tags: ios, xcode7

I am a newbie. I bumped into a few problems in the course of developing iOS swift app. with your explanation, I will learn how to use the best practices.
here my questions I wanted to know the reasons and use the simple ways to solve:

I accidentally deleted the main.storyboard file. However, I got back up. I thought to start fresh. I delete the project and created a new one with exact same name. I deleted the new main storyboard file in it and copy the old main story file as well as the other files into Top level folder (App folder). I rebuilt it and it run.

here my questions:

1. I see other samples, I notice the Main storyboard file is inside Base.lproj folder. But in my project, the main storyboard file is not in it when open in Xcode v7.3. I open the App Folder in DeskTop, I dont see main storyboard file in Base.lproj. But this file is in App Folder. is this ok?
2. I run it a couple of time, I don't see Tests folder like ProjectNameTests as well. Is this ok?
3. If I manually move the main storyboard file into Base.lproj, it will have compiling issue.
4. is this way of restoring files ok? Copy the old files into the Top level folder ok?
5. What will be the correct ways to handle if I have backup for project.

Apprciate your help on this matter.

Thanks

Comment: xcode does not care about project files organization as long as it has correct path to file

Comment: can u advise for point 2 and 5. Thanks

Comment: when you are creating a project you can mark to add tests or just http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865735/adding-unit-tests-to-an-already-existing-project

Comment: project backups only GIT

Comment: Sorry , didn't say it clearer. What if I back up the project Folder into Thumb Drive.  I can restore whichever VC files in the project in MacBook as long as in my ThumbDrive I have the main storyboard file and the VC files. I can delete all the files and replace them with the same name files in my Thumbdrive. If VC1 is not the same as old VC1, it will replace the VC1 currently in the project.

Comment: don't you think this will be easier to just check by yourself?